# Permissibility of making Matzah by frying

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, cooking-bishul, matzah

Does anyone know of an opinion permitting Matzah to be cooked in a skillet(instead of being baked in an oven), and if so under what circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch 461:2 refers to an "ilfas," which is a kind of wide pan used for baking. The SA rules that it needs to be pre-heated before use. Actually, the Menachos in the Beis Hamikdash, which had to be matzah, were baked in pans. So it is definitely *possible*. But whether it is allowed *l'maaseh* is an entirely different story.

Comment: Should we be commenting on whether or not it would not be "allowed" LeMa'aseh?  Wouldn't a better question be whether it is possible LeMa'aseh?  If nobody has done it in centuries (and I don't know that that's the case), it might not be possible to ensure that one does it correctly.  There might be some level of training under competent supervision that would be advisable over the course of the year (or several years) before one can be comfortable doing it for Pesah.  But who is the one doing the "allowing"?  It's a matter of whether or not one does it correctly 'Al Pi Halachah.

Comment: My understanding of the "lifas" was that it was bowl shaped object which was heated, and then inverted so that things were baked beneath it.

Comment: @mekubal - actually the full phrase is "ilfas b'lo mayim." Clearly the reference is to a pan being used in the ordinary, right-side-up way, just without water.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but the Arukh HaShulchan says differently.

Comment: @mekubal - are we talking about the same Aruch Hashulchan?? The one I have refers to a "machavas," which is unquestionably an ordinary frying pan. In fact, based on this AH I would say that the answer to your questions is yes, one may bake matzah in a pre-heated skillet without liquid.

Comment: Yes that is the one.  But he goes on to say that things are baked under it, and thus it bakes it from above.  Between his description and the M"B's it leaves me with the feeling that it is a clay bowl that is heated and then inverted to form an "oven".  
The Kaf HaHaim references it as a pot and says to see the Gemarra Pesachim 37a.  There they speak of it as a mould into which bread was pressed to shape it. 
I am simply having difficulty reconciling any description with a skillet as we have today.

Comment: The AH does not say anything about baking under it. His wording is: וכן כשאופה במחבת בלא משקה יזהר להסיק תחתיו תחילה עד שיהיה מרותח היטב ואח"כ ידביק הפת בתוכה . Translation: Similarly, when one bakes in a frying pan without liquid, he should be careful to light the fire under it first until it is very hot, and [only] afterwards stick the dough into it.

Comment: this is the very question in the gemara pesachim 37a/b. עיין שם ותמצא נחת.

Comment: @moses - It seems to me that the discussion there in Pesachim is whether dough baked in a pan has the status of "pas" ("bread"). I think most of us here are discussing whether frying in a pan is an acceptable way of producing chametz-free matzah. These are entirely different issues.

Comment: @Dave I'm with Dave: The Aruch Hashulchan (and indeed the Shulchan Aruch) clearly say that this is permissible. You do need to heat it first, and don't add any liquid. I think that Igros Moshe 1:153 would require you to cover the pan so that the top of the matzo gets heated as well.